# Make The 3rd row as Header of Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data in a csv as below, the first row is blank and the second row is filled for only the 4 columns as below,

```
        201901                201902           201903       201904
A   X   1           0       1       1
B   Y   0           0       1       1
A   Z   1           0       1       1
B   X   1           0       1       1
A   Y   0           0       0       1
B   Z   1           0       0       1
A   X   0           1       0       1
B   Y   1           1       0       0
A   Z   1           1       0       0
B   X   0           1       1       0
```

If I read the data into csv i will get the data as below

```
_c1     _c2     _c3         _c4     _c5     _c6
null           null        null            null       null  null
null           null       201901                201902          201903  201904
A       X       1           0       1       1
B       Y       0           0       1       1
A       Z       1           0       1       1
B       X       1           0       1       1
A       Y       0           0       0       1
B       Z       1           0       0       1
A       X       0           1       0       1
B       Y       1           1       0       0
A       Z       1           1       0       0
B       X       0           1       1       0
```

I have read the datafile without header and removed the not required headers. Now I want to convert the files to have header

```
df=spark.read.csv("s3://abc/def/file.csv",header=False)
df=df.where(col("_c3").isNotNull())
```

```
Type         Source         201901                 201902           201903  201904
A       X       1           0       1       1
B       Y       0           0       1       1
A       Z       1           0       1       1
B       X       1           0       1       1
A       Y       0           0       0       1
B       Z       1           0       0       1
A       X       0           1       0       1
B       Y       1           1       0       0
A       Z       1           1       0       0
B       X       0           1       1       0
```

Answer (score -2):

you can create a custom schema by defining it something like this

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("yourcolumnheader", StringType, true),
    StructField("yourcolumnheader2", StringType, true),
    StructField("yourcolumnheader3", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("yourcolumnheader4", DoubleType, true)))
```

then use that schema when you read your formatted  ie 3 rows removed CSV file

```
df=spark.read.csv("s3://abc/def/file.csv",header=False)
.schema(customeSchema)
```

hope that answers your question.